# Is it a bad idea to save POST information without using django Forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am currently developing a student survey app.

when the student clicks the submit button on the form, activate the view with the following code:

```
for key, value in request.POST.items(): 
       if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': # I don't want to save the token info
          item = Item.objects.get(pk=key) # I get the question(item) I want to save
          if item == None:
            return render(request, "survey/error.html")
          Answer.objects.create(item= item, answer=value, user = request.user)
```

Since all the fields in the form are obligatory, I use the required value attribute in html.

This code works and stores the information in the DB. However, I am concerned that because it is very "manual", it may generate errors when it is in production.

However I do not know how to use django forms, so I would like to avoid having to learn it, if it is not necessary.

Comment: "*Since all the fields in the form are obligatory, I use the required value attribute in html.*". The fact that you specify that in HTML unfortunately does *not* guarantee you anything. After all the HTML is just something that tells the browser how it is *supposed* to render the content, and how to make the request. But a hacker, or a horrible browser can just do with it whatever it wants. So it is a common hacking technique to try "spoofing" requests, and see how the program reacts. You can not trust anything at the client side. This is one of the aspects a form aims to tackle.

Comment: Even if we are not interested in security, then there are other prblems. For example here if the third element is invalid, then `.get(..)` will raise an error, not return `None`, but even if we fix that, it is still not a good function, since now if halfway we spot an error, that means a part of the elements are processed, and another part is not. Typically one first wants to validate the form, and only if the form completely makes sense, do processing. A form helps to "enforce" that, by encapsulating a lot of logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your answer. So your advice is that I should learn to use django forms, right?